# flutter hive local storage

Tags: flutter

i'm working on a flutter project and i'm using Hive as a local storage but still i can't implement what i want which is for example i have already declared `bool x = false;` and `bool y = false;` then i want in a onPressed function i will say that `x = true;` and `y = true` and without any packages at all the new values will be true but my problem is that i need to save the last changes which is true because when i restart my app it returns to the old value which is false

so is there anyway to implement that with hive in easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  // Initialize Hive
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox('myBox');
  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hive Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool x = false;
  bool y = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    // Retrieve save boolean values from Hive
    Box box = Hive.box('myBox');
    x = box.get('x', defaultValue: false);
    y = box.get('y', defaultValue: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hive Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('x: $x'),
            Text('y: $y'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Update boolean values'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Update boolean values and save to Hive
                setState(() {
                  x = true;
                  y = true;
                });
                Box box = Hive.box('myBox');
                box.put('x', x);
                box.put('y', y);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```